# How can I ensure webpack-dev-server recompiles Sass when using a custom Sass importer?

Tags: webpack, sass, node-sass, sass-loader, hot-reload

I'm using a [custom Sass importer](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental) that lets me import JavaScript/JSON files into my Sass. The issue I'm having is that when I save some JavaScript file that is being imported into my Sass, it doesn't trigger a hot-update/reload when using `webpack-dev-server`.

If I import the file in question inside my main app's JavaScript as well, saving it works as expected (it will trigger a successful re-compile).

For some more context, I have a UI component that has an `index.js` file. Inside this `index.js` file I'm importing a Sass file. Inside this Sass file is where I'm importing my JavaScript file that doesn't trigger a reload when saving.

I'm not really sure if this is a Node-Sass issue or a Webpack issue but everything else is working as expected. I can import other Sass files into the main Sass file and saving those will trigger a hot-reload/update.

Answer (score 0):

I got to the bottom of this. Inside my custom Sass Importer, I was returning with:

```js
{ contents: "String" }
```

...as per [the Node-Sass docs](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental). I should have instead returned with:

```js
{ 
  file: "String",
  contents: "String" 
}
```

With `file` being the computed path to the imported file. Without passing this, Node/Webpack will not be aware of the file so will not be watching it for changes.